# GORM does not output related data

Tags: go, go-gorm

I ran into the following problem:
I specified relationships in the data structures, but some data is output empty.
For example: I get data on a product, the price is pulled up, the stocks are pulled up, but the data on the store where they are located is not pulled up to the stock.

**The structures that I use:**

```
type Product struct {
    Id          uint    `json:"id"`
    Code        int     `json:"code" gorm:"index"`
    ProductName string  `json:"name"`
    Brand       string  `json:"brand"`
    Price       Price   `json:"price" gorm:"foreignKey:ProductCode;references:Code"`
    Stocks      []Stock `json:"stock" gorm:"foreignKey:ProductCode;references:Code"`
}

type Stock struct {
    ProductCode int   `json:"product_code"`
    StoreCode   uint  `json:"store_code" gorm:"index;"`
    Quantity    int   `json:"quantity"`
    Store       Store `json:"store" gorm:"foreignKey:StoreId;references:StoreCode;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Timestamp   int64 `json:"timestamp"`
}

type Price struct {
    ProductCode    int   `json:"product_code"`
    OldPrice       int   `json:"old_price"`
    CurrentPrice   int   `json:"current_price"`
    WholesalePrice int   `json:"wholesale_price"`
    Timestamp      int64 `json:"timestamp"`
}

type Store struct {
    Id           uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    StoreKaspiId string `json:"store_kaspi_id"`
    StoreId      uint   `json:"store_id"`
    CityId       uint   `json:"city_id"`
    City         City   `json:"city" gorm:"foreignKey:CityId"`
    StoreAddress string `json:"store_address"`
}

type City struct {
    Id   uint   `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

**Query result:**

```
{
    "id": 79,
    "code": 687,
    "name": "Электромясорубка Аксион M21.03",
    "brand": "Аксион",
    "price": {
        "product_code": 687,
        "old_price": 30990,
        "current_price": 23910,
        "wholesale_price": 19900,
        "timestamp": 1628824966063
    },
    "stock": [
        {
            "product_code": 687,
            "store_code": 15,
            "quantity": 37,
            "store": {
                "id": 0,
                "store_kaspi_id": "",
                "store_id": 0,
                "city_id": 0,
                "city": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": ""
                },
                "store_address": ""
            },
            "timestamp": 1628824966219
        },
        {
            "product_code": 687,
            "store_code": 20,
            "quantity": 39,
            "store": {
                "id": 0,
                "store_kaspi_id": "",
                "store_id": 0,
                "city_id": 0,
                "city": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": ""
                },
                "store_address": ""
            },
            "timestamp": 1628824966219
        },
        {
            "product_code": 687,
            "store_code": 42,
            "quantity": 39,
            "store": {
                "id": 0,
                "store_kaspi_id": "",
                "store_id": 0,
                "city_id": 0,
                "city": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": ""
                },
                "store_address": ""
            },
            "timestamp": 1628824966219
        },
        {
            "product_code": 687,
            "store_code": 45,
            "quantity": 47,
            "store": {
                "id": 0,
                "store_kaspi_id": "",
                "store_id": 0,
                "city_id": 0,
                "city": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": ""
                },
                "store_address": ""
            },
            "timestamp": 1628824966219
        }
    ]
}
```

**Please help me understand!**

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Please provide the actual code fetching the results. However, It looks like you're not using Preload("Stock.Store")

Comment: Thank you for the hint! This helped solve the problem! I have used Preload ("Stocks") before